# Can yugabyteDB used for storage & streaming?

Tags: database, streaming, yugabytedb, gocql

We have GoLang backend service used to:

1. Store data in yugabyte DB using YCL driver
2. Publish the same data to Kafka

Step 2 was necessary so that consumers can stream through kafka

1. Can yugabyteDB help stream data, once a new row created in a table? to avoid maintainence of state in kafka....
2. if yes, does yugabyte db support streaming with push model?

Answer (score 1):

CDC feature is actively being worked on at https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/9019. Also support for 2, pushing into kafka is in the works.

Comment: I mean, push model for consumers to subscribe messages

Comment: I don't think so as of now. You can ask on the github issue for more clarity.